# socket server framework like Tcl "socket -server"

Tags: python, socketserver, event-loop

I'm looking to reimplement some Tcl code that uses the `socket -server` construct [1].

What's the best option in Python for a small, industrial strength multi-user network-based server that includes event loop processing/integration?

[1] http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/socket.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like Python's [`socketserver`](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html) module.

There are more advanced frameworks too, [`asyncore`](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html) is included in the stdlib and [`twisted`](http://twistedmatrix.com/) is a huge networking framework.